# How do I nest a Windows FOR command in the 'set' of another FOR command?

Tags: windows, command-line, syntax

I have a directory of configuration files.  If a file contains a 'STATE = 3' entry, I want to extract the value of the TCPHOST entry and the name of the file.  There are a lot of nested quotes in that so I used "usebackq" but without success:

```
c:\config>For /F "usebackq tokens=1,3 delims==: " %A in (`FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %P IN ('FINDSTR /M /I /R /C:"*STATE.*=.*3" * ') DO ('FINDSTR /I /S /C:"TCPHOST" %P')`) do (echo '%A|http://%B')

`) was unexpected at this time.
```

I have replaced the inner "FOR" command with a simple "DIR" and the results are technically correct (albeit meaningless) - I display the first and third tokens of the output.

Am I trying to do something impossible with these commands.  (I am aware that I could probably write a bat file or PowerShell script but that's not my question.)

Comment: (1) It might help if you showed sample input and expected output.  (2) Better yet, explain what you expect to see at each step.  (3) Have you tried running each step by itself?  (3a) In particular, I get an error from `FINDSTR /M /I /R /C:"*STATE.*=.*3" *`, apparently because your regular expression begins with `*`, which is incorrect.  (3b) The `/S` in `FINDSTR /I /S /C:"TCPHOST" %P` seems wrong.  What sense does it make to specify a recursive search of a single file?   … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) Rather than stub out an inner nesting layer, it probably makes more sense to keep the innermost layers as is and strip off the outer layer(s).  (5) In any case, please show us exactly what you tried and what results you got.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the result that (I guess) you want, sticking to CMD,
but breaking your monster command into multiple steps,
with an intermediate file:

```
copy/y nul %temp%\out1.txt
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %P IN ('FINDSTR /M /I /R /C:"STATE.*=.*3" * ') DO (FINDSTR /I /S /C:"TCPHOST" %P) >> %temp%\out1.txt
For /F "tokens=1,3 delims==: " %A in (%temp%\out1.txt) do (echo '%A^|http://%B')
del %temp%\out1.txt
```

I can’t figure out exactly why you got the error you got,
but here are a few possible show-stoppers in your code:

- `"*STATE.*=.*3"` should be `"STATE.*=.*3"` (or maybe `".*STATE.*=.*3"`)
  because starting a regular expression with `*` is invalid.
- `DO ('FINDSTR /I /S /C:"TCPHOST" %P')` should be `DO (FINDSTR /I /S /C:"TCPHOST" %P)` — the command after `DO` shouldn’t be in quotes.
- `echo '%A|http://%B'` should be `echo '%A^|http://%B'`
  (to get a literal **`|`** rather than trying
  to pipe `echo '%A` into `http://%B'`)
  or maybe `echo %A^|http://%B`
  (to avoid getting single quotes in the output — or do you want them?).

Comment: Thanks Scott.
The various separate components do actually work (I dropped the . before the * in the regex pasting the command above - sorry bout that!).

\config>For /F "usebackq tokens=1,3 delims==: " %A in (`FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %P IN ('FINDSTR /M /I /R /C:".*STATE.*=.*3" *') DO (FINDSTR /I /C:"TCPHOST" %P)`) do (echo %A^|http://%B)

I applied the various changes you suggested but still I get the same error. (...cont'd)

Comment: (...cont'd) The input files are simple "key = value" configuration files:
INSTALLSTATE = 3
...
TCPHOST = somehost.somecompany.com

Comment: (...cont'd)
The hope is %P returns the filename if the file contains '.*STATE = 3'.  The inner FOR command should then become a 'set' of filenames.
The outer FOR command should look in each returned file and set %A to the filename and %B to the value after 'TCPHOST ='.
The end result will be `filename|http://somehost.somecompany.com`